# Every open set $U \subset \Bbb R$ is a part of $Q(\Bbb R)^\uparrow$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Q(\Bbb R)$ be the set of every half-open interval $[a, b)$ $\subset$ $\Bbb R$, and let $Q(\Bbb R)^\uparrow$ be the set of every $A \in \mathscr P(\Bbb R)$ with $A_k \uparrow A$, $A_k \in Q(\Bbb R)$, which means that $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \ ... \ $ and $\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k = A$. Plus, take a look at the following theorem:

Every open set $U \subset \Bbb R$ is a disjoint union of countable half-open cubes with rational endpoints.

Now, my book states the following:

From the theorem above, it follows that every open set is a part of $Q(\Bbb R)^\uparrow$.

I don't see why this is the case. The theorem works under the premise that the cubes are disjoint to each other, but when we have an open set that is a part of $Q(\Bbb R)^\uparrow$, it is a union of sets that obviously aren't disjoint to each other. So how does this fit together?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming each $A_k$ is supposed to be a union of elements of $Q(\mathbb{R})$ (If $A_k$ is constrained to be a member of $Q(\mathbb{R})$, then any disconnected open set is a counterexample to the theorem - any increasing union of connected sets is going to remain connected, and half-open intervals are connected). If we can write $U$ as the disjoint union $U=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty [a_k,b_k)$, then we can also write

$$
[a_1,b_1) \subset [a_1,b_1) \cup [a_2,b_2) \subset \ldots \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^m [a_k,b_k) \subset \ldots 
$$

which increases to $U$.

Comment: There is another definition in my book, saying that $Q(\Bbb R)^\uparrow$  can also be understood as the set of all sets that can be written as a union of a countable family of elements of $Q(\Bbb R)$, which might be easier to handle in this situation since it doesn't contradict the property of the sets being disjoint by premise. Plus, isn't  a cube in $\Bbb R$ just an intervall too?

Comment: But it's actually true that the $A_k$ must be a part of $Q(\Bbb R)$, at least that's what he tells in the definition. So yeah, that's a little bit confusing.

Comment: I put it in the main post as a correction.

Comment: On the one hand, every open interval $(a,b)$ can be presented as a union of a countable   family of  pairwise disjoint  half-open intervals. On the other hand, every open  set can be presented as  a union of  a countable family  of pairwise disjoint open  intervals.